# spring-boot redisTemplate execute script error: EvalSha is not supported in cluster environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-redis

Trying to execute lua script using redisTemplate, in a spring-boot project. Looks like jedis does not support executing lua script for redis cluster... Is there any other alternatives? Thanks!

redis config:

```
spring:
  redis:
    cluster:
      nodes:
        - 192.168.0.111:6390
        - 192.168.0.111:6391
        - 192.168.0.111:6392
```

code:

```
@Component
public class Example {

@Autowired
private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;

@Autowired
RedisScript<Boolean> script;

public boolean checkAndSet(String expectedValue, String newValue) {
    return (boolean) redisTemplate.execute(script, singletonList("key1"), asList(expectedValue, newValue));
}
}
```

error logs:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: EvalSha is not supported in cluster environment.

at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.evalSha(JedisClusterConnection.java:3568)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.invoke(CloseSuppressingInvocationHandler.java:57)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.evalSha(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.eval(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:81)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor$1.doInRedis(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:71)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:207)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:157)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:60)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.script.DefaultScriptExecutor.execute(DefaultScriptExecutor.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:300)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to the Lettuce driver to use `EVALSHA` in a cluster environment.

A configuration for Spring Boot 1.5.x could look like:

```
@Bean
LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory(RedisProperties redisProperties) {

    Cluster clusterProperties = redisProperties.getCluster();
    RedisClusterConfiguration config = new RedisClusterConfiguration(
            clusterProperties.getNodes());

    if (clusterProperties.getMaxRedirects() != null) {
        config.setMaxRedirects(clusterProperties.getMaxRedirects());
    }

    return new LettuceConnectionFactory(config);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example for spring-boot using Lettuce?